# What could be the reason I only see my group in parentheses in the file manager in the owner column?

Tags: filemanager, thunar, ownership

I decided to reinstall Xubuntu 14.04 LTS after I botched an earlier install. After the reinstall I copied the backup I had, of my home directory, back in place (same username, same uid (1000), same group (not sure about the gid though, but presumably the same as well)) using `dd` from a live usb session.

If I remember correctly, in the earlier install I saw the following in the file manager's (Thunar) owner columns on the files I own:

`username (group)` (both have the same name in actuality)

... just like I do for other files, not owned by me. For instance for `root:root` I'd see:

`root (root)`

But on my new install I only see this in the owner column, when the files are owned by me:

`(group)` (the actual group name in actuality)

Doing `ls -al` in terminal in the same folders will show the correct user for the owner column.

What could be the reason I'm only seeing the group name in parentheses now, in the owner column in Thunar? And how, if at all possible, can I fix this?

Comment: Could it be to the fact that it would just be redundancy?

Comment: @Mew I doubt that. On an updated Arch, a fresh install of Thunar still follows the "Full Name (username)" format, where Full Name is from the GECOS data. However, it does not use `username (group)`, like OP says. Is OP mistaken or does Xubuntu configure somehow? I couldn't find anything in the ["hidden" options](http://docs.xfce.org/xfce/thunar/hidden-settings) of Thunar either.

Comment: @muru I was mistaken indeed! It's not `username (group)` indeed (I don't know what I was thinking, because what you say makes more sense after all). So everything is cleared up right now. If you transform your comment into an answer I'll select it as best answer and award you the bounty.

Comment: Was that all? I thought the owner column only shows `(group)` and not `Full Name (username)` for you. Is that fixed?

Comment: @muru Yeah, it is; I got confused because my `Full Name` is empty and both my `username` and `group` have the same name. I therefore thought the name in parentheses in the owner column represented my `group`, when in fact it was my `username`. It also didn't occur to me that `root` has a full name (`root`) as well. It all makes sense to me now. I wasn't thinking clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The owner column in Thunar (in a fresh install in an up-to-date Arch Linux setup, as well as in Ubuntu 14.04) uses the `Full Name (username)` format, where the "Full Name" is taken from the GECOS data for the user. If the GECOS data is empty, it just shows `(user)`. Most system/package-created users (like `root`, `nobody`, `pulse`, etc.) have something in the GECOS name field (`root`, `nobody` and `PulseAudio daemon` respectively). So system files will likely have a complete entry in the owner column.